# Select rows based on some value in a column and remove duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset in Pandas where I have columns like:

```
brand    categories  
nike     sandals
nike     sneakers   
adidas   sneakers
adidas   sneakers
puma     boots
puma     boots
fila     sneakers
```

I want to keep the rows with `brands` containing only "sneaker" and have all duplicate rows removed.

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: What did you do to remove the duplicates? can you share the code that removes the duplicates and an example of what is printed? it is hard to help you here without knowing why your solution is failing.

Comment: to remove the duplicates , I did this : df2.categories.drop_duplicates(keep='first') and df2.brand.drop_duplicates(keep='first')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df1 = df[df.categories.str.contains('sneakers', case=False)]
```

From your orignal pandas dataset use this to take out the needed items.Then delete or just forget the orignal dataframe i.e.

```
del df
```

because your new dataframe is df1

Comment: hello, when i do that , it says empty data frame. the rows are like this: Sneakers,Women,Shoes Under $100 \ Shoes,Sneakers,Women's Shoes \ ecc

Comment: @lea check now.

Comment: @Vishnudev after I do that,  do I need to create a new data frame with only the needed items?  I don't understand what you mean by "delete or just forget".

Comment: @lea did this explanation help

Answer (score 0):

Select the rows which have category as Sneakers and drop duplicate rows,

```
condition = df.categories.str.contains('sneakers', case=False)
df = df[condition].drop_duplicates(keep='first')
```

Output

```
    brand categories
1    nike   sneakers
2  adidas   sneakers
6    fila   sneakers
```

Comment: hello, the condition code worked, but when i try to run df code , the output says : Boolean array expected for the condition, not object

Comment: What does `print(condition)` give? Check your code, might be a typo?